# How is jitter determined in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, point, jitter

I was looking over the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_jitter.html) on jitter in ggplot while making some plots, and I realized that I don't really understand the argument.

It states that the arguments are:

`Width:  degree of jitter in x direction. Defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data.` 
  and
`height: degree of jitter in y direction. Defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data.`

My question is, what exactly is resolution, and how is it determined?

Also, you can override this and provide a value, like in the example below where we use 0.1:

`geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0.1, h = 0.1))`

What units belong to 0.1? Am I right to assume that this some proportion of the resolution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look at the [source](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-jitter.r) we first find this:

```
PositionJitter <- proto(Position, {
  objname <- "jitter"

  adjust <- function(., data) {
    if (empty(data)) return(data.frame())
    check_required_aesthetics(c("x", "y"), names(data), "position_jitter")

    if (is.null(.$width)) .$width <- resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * 0.4
    if (is.null(.$height)) .$height <- resolution(data$y, zero = FALSE) * 0.4

    trans_x <- NULL
    trans_y <- NULL
    if(.$width > 0) {
      trans_x <- function(x) jitter(x, amount = .$width)
    }
    if(.$height > 0) {
      trans_y <- function(x) jitter(x, amount = .$height)
    }

    transform_position(data, trans_x, trans_y)
  }

})
```

And wouldn't you know it, `resolution` is an exported function (or you could just search the sources for it landing you [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/4bb9270ef4d5d5062353438fd99d17b6f6de98a2/R/utilities-resolution.r)):

```
function (x, zero = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.integer(x) || zero_range(range(x, na.rm = TRUE))) 
        return(1)
    x <- unique(as.numeric(x))
    if (zero) {
        x <- unique(c(0, x))
    }
    min(diff(sort(x)))
}
```

So...there you go!

"resolution" in this context then roughly means "the smallest distance between any two elements in a vector".

This value (40% of the resolution) is then passed on as the `factor` argument to `jitter`, which has it's own little song and dance:

> The result, say r, is r <- x + runif(n, -a, a) where n <- length(x)
>   and a is the amount argument (if specified).
>
> Let z <- max(x) - min(x) (assuming the usual case). The amount a to be
>   added is either provided as positive argument amount or otherwise
>   computed from z, as follows:
>
> If amount == 0, we set a <- factor * z/50 (same as S).
>
> If amount is NULL (default), we set a <- factor * d/5 where d is the
>   smallest difference between adjacent unique (apart from fuzz) x
>   values.